# How can I know if my website is vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, code-injection

I know that this question has been asked by many people but unfortunately I couldn't find the proper answer for my question.

In all the articles that I have read about SQL Injection, they talk about the URLs such that
http://www.example.com/member.php?id=1
and how I can check if my website is vulnerable to SQL Injection using (').

In my case, my website is such that:
http://www.example.com/Login.php
As you can see I don't have ?id=1, What should I do to test my website?

Thank you

Comment: You should really get more information about the issue. Every single beginner's article I ever read about MySQL injection mentioned the `' or ''='` trick that could be of interest here.

Comment: Also, its easiest to just examine the source code of the application to check whether it properly escapes database input.

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer almost certainly is that your site's vulnerable.

Answer (score 5):

You are vulnerable to SQL Injection through the use of hardcoded variable portions of your query.  In other words, using named parameters prevents this.

If you just blindly take strings and *inject* them into your queries without parameters or sanitation, you are basically allowing public people (i.e. potentially bad people) direct access to write SQL code against your database.

**SQL Injection** is a topic that is hard to fit in an SO answer, so I highly recommend the [Wikipedia article on SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I always thought "hard-coded" and "variable" were the exact opposite of each other. +1 however because it's his own webapp and he should have access to the source code.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark What I mean by hardcoded variables is something like `sqlQuery = "select * from SomeTable where username = '" + UserNameTextBox.Text + "'";`.  These are what I'd consider "hard-coded variables", because this is what the database engine see: `select * from SomeTable where username = 'someuser'`.  But the database engine should be seeing `select * from SomeTable where username = @userNameVariable`.

Comment: Okay, now I see. What confused me was that you can also have hard-coded, but sanitized strings in the query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection is the ability to inject SQL queries directly into your websites preconfigured code.  This can be done with something as simple as a ';' symbol added to append your code, but is in no way limited to this.

To check your site for XSS the best thing to do is verify that all of the inputs taken from the webpage are verified prior to running against your database.  For instance, this means that within your application's code you are verifying that the post button on your website only contains parameters that you are expecting and nothing more.  Field verification and limits are the main vulnerabilities that you are trying to limit.

Do not use your webpage as a verification tool.  Hackers looking to exploit XSS will not necessarily be using your page to do this.  This means your business logic is what needs to be assessed.

Answer (score 0):

You are vulnerable to SQL Injection if you accept user input and you use SQL.  Whether or not you have sufficiently protected yourself against SQL injection is another question.